# Set width as percentage but render divs evenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a graphing function for .Net MVC to produce a pure HTML bar graph. I want to set the width of each bar to be a percentage of the parent div so that the chart scales correctly if the user re-sizes the browser.

However, I will normally have around 300 bars in the graph so the width of each bar ends up being computed at 1.54px (for example). This does horrible things to how the browser renders the bars (in IE and chrome at least).

[image: Example bar chart]

This uneven rendering of the bars goes away if I set a fixed width to each bar with an integer value of pixels (i.e. 2px, not 1.6px). However if I do this the the chart won't scale with the browser.

Is there a "best practice" solution to this problem? Can I get the bars to scale with the browser without allowing non-integer values for the width of the bars?

EDIT: One other point to note, my boss has a pathological mistrust of 3rd party libraries, hence writing the function from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://d3js.org/ this is a library for all sorts of graphs. It takes care of calculating the spaces. Has nice effects and is easy to use with binding in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As silverfighter pointed out, there are a lot of graphing libraries for a variety of graphs. These solutions are again divided into Canvas based and HTML based. The canvas based libraries may not work on certain old browsers. Some solutions such as google charts are a little better at handling old browsers.

So, depending on the support you want to provide for old browsers, you can choose between the libraries. A simple google search gave me the below link
http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries

Canvas based - d3js.org, visjs.org
https://developers.google.com/chart/

If you still fixated on writing your own code to positioning a div relatively, the "auto" value for the "margin" css tag should help.

[Edit] - Sorry misread the question and thought the problem was with the height. The width can be set after the graph data is available using javascript. Assign a class to each bar, calculate available width and then divide by your total count. So, you get the width dynamically based on the page size.